# Exibir no template o valor de um objeto ManyToMany Django?

Tags: django

Hei, desculpem a pergunta confusa (não sei exatamente como perguntar isso), mas vamos lá.
Estou usando Django2.1.

Tenho esses 2 `models` relacionados de maneira `ManyToMany`:

```
class Ingrediente(models.Model):
produtor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=10)
nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
descricao = models.TextField()
quantidade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
```

e

```
class Produto(models.Model):
nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
descricao = models.TextField()
ingredientes = models.ManyToManyField(Ingrediente)
utilitarios = models.ManyToManyField(OutrosCustos)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
```

Uso a seguinte `view` para retornar uma lista com todos os objetos da classe Produto:

```
def produtos_list(request):
produtos = Produto.objects.filter()
return render(request, 'egg_app/produtos_list.html', {'produtos':produtos})
```

Aí a brincadeira, no meu template eu retorno dessa forma:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nº Produto</th>
        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
        <th scope="col">Ingredientes</th>
        <th scope="col">Custo</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for p in produtos %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ p.pk }}</th>
            <td>{{ p.nome }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.ingredientes }}</td>
            <td>custo teste</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

E o meu resultado tem sido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que, na coluna Ingredientes, houvessem os nomes dos Ingredientes e não esse Ingrediente.None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá, consegui uma solução.

Primeiramente, a exibição que eu estava tentando não era agradável, então eu mudei as coisas. Ao invés de lançar tudo nessa tabela, eu fiz um link no nome de cada produto, e o lancei para uma página de detalhes individuais. E lá eu fiz uma listagem da seguinte lógica:

Para retornar uma lista com o QuerySet de todos os objetos, eu preciso disso (que me ensinaram [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427575/how-to-use-a-atribbute-of-a-object-many-to-many-in-djangoresolved):

```
 produtos.ingredientes.all
```

Mas infelizmente isso retorna uma QuerySet pura, algo como:

```
<QuerySet [<Ingrediente: Ingrediente Teste 1>, <Ingrediente: Ingrediente Teste 2>]>
```

Ainda no mesmo comentário, o amigo me sugeriu um for, e então eu o fiz e dessa maneira consegui o resultado esperado:

```
{% for ingredientes_desse_produto in produtos.ingredientes.all %}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ ingredientes_desse_produto.nome }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ ingredientes_desse_produto.custo }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Eu percorro todos os resultados com o primeiro for, e uso os atributos individuais do objeto logo abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a imagem , a variável "ingredientes" está vazio, o padrão do Django é a variável começar "None"(vazio) , então o problema deve ser no inicio. deve ser um pequeno erro de digitação. 
Você esta usando a classe produto para lista, verifique onde o a variável "ingredientes" recebe os dados,o problema deve estar no ali.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459890/django-template-display-item-value-or-empty-string

Comment: hei Rodrigo, valeu a ajuda, estive ausente uns dias então demorei para testar. No stack overflow internacional me passaram essa sintaxe {{ produtos.ingredientes.all }}, ela retorna os ingredientes, porém como query set. Meu desafio por agora está sendo trazer apenas o atributo nome da classe Ingredientes, numa lista de Produtos ( isso pode ser confuso, mas se olhar ali o código acho que dá para entender).

Comment: eu verifiquei a pergunta que você mandou linkada, e não é o caso também

Comment: update: eu consegui, vou fazer uma outra resposta aqui para mostrar já já. Mas muito obrigado!